# How do we pronounce this symbol $'$ for $p',q'$, etc. And why?

Tags: soft-question, notation

This symbol $'$ for $p',q'$, etc; I know $'$, it is called **prum**(?) or something close to that, and $p',q'$ are p prum, q prum.

But what exactly is $'$ written or pronounced? Thanks.

And why is that called **prum**(?)?

Comment: It's called "prime".

Comment: why prime? it is not prime number.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)#History

Comment: Thanks all, any of this is good enough for an answer.

Comment: @par Would you like to flesh your link out to an answer?

Comment: I've heard it called dash as well. Mostly when you're using it as a modified version version of another variable. e.g. p and p' (p dash)

Comment: I'm still wondering why the word for inflection point in German comes out `watershed.' Also, what is a watershed. Meanwhile, Wendepunkt...

Comment: Previously: [How do you pronounce the symbol $'$ in $f'$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/47339/856)