# What are these tick marks after the x, y, and z called?

Tags: matrices, notation

[image]

What are these marks called and what do they stand for?

This is for a Affine Transformation.

Comment: prime?other variables corresponding to x,y,z?

Comment: This needs more context.

Comment: The marks you see that look like ' over the x , y, and z.

Comment: Related: [How do you pronounce the symbol $\prime$ in $f′$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47339/how-do-you-pronounce-the-symbol-in-f/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually stand for the variable or function after some type of transformation has been done to it such as maybe taking the derivative of a function or rotating a variable about the x axis, or as in the example above $[x',y',z']$ represent the $[x.y.z]$ vector after it has gone through the matrix transformation. Z' can be pronounced as "Z prime"

Comment: I kinda thought that, but didn't know for sure.