# How do you pronounce x' and x''?

Tags: pronunciation

I am giving a presentation tonight, and the mathematical terms x' and x'' feature heavily in it. I pronounce them as "x-dash" and "x-dash-dash", but this gets a bit tiresome by the end of the presentation.

A - Am I correct in pronouncing them this way?
B - Is there an alternative way of saying x' and x'' that is less of a mouthful?

Comment: They are *x prime* and *x double prime*. A dash is a hyphen, so *x dash* is definitely not correct.

Comment: x prime or x double prime...

Comment: Dash would be x-.

Comment: If you want to be old-fashioned, you can say "$x$ prime", "$x$ second", "$x$ third", etc.

Comment: I use "x prime" and "x prime prime" myself. (I don't like "double prime" since it feels like an abbreviation that is actually longer than what it abbreviates)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pronounce the symbol $'$ in $f'$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47339/how-do-you-pronounce-the-symbol-in-f)

Comment: Wow, we have a pronunciation tag?

Answer (score 7):

x' is *x prime*.
x'' is *x double prime*.

Answer (score 3):

$x$ *dash* is common in the UK for $x'$.  So Brian is definitely not correct when he says "$x$ *dash* is definitely not correct".  [Since I am in the US, I definitely hear $x$ *prime* primarily, though.] Griffin2000 does not say where he is.

Littlewood has a joke about this in his *Miscellany*.  Derived sets in point-set topology are denoted like $E'$.  Some mathematician was talking about something that would hold for such derived sets, and ended up saying "for any dashed set" ...

Answer (score 2):

x', x prime, is the first derivative of x and x'', x double prime, is the second derivative of x. I have never heard of x dash before, but I have see alternative versions of writing x' and x''. Almost two years ago, I had an ODE book that wrote $\dot x$ (first derivative) and $\ddot x$ (second derivative). It was strange, but eventually I got used to its meaning.